# Cargo.toml: how do I select a dependency's feature based on my crate's features?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo, toml

The scenario is the following: my crate has a dependency on [`num-bigint`](https://crates.io/crates/num-bigint), and an optional dependency on [`rand`](https://crates.io/crates/rand):

```
[dependencies]
num-bigint = { version = "0.2" }
rand = { version = "0.7", optional = true }
```

When `rand` is disabled on my crate, everything's fine.

**When `rand` is enabled on my crate, I would like the `rand` feature of `num-bigint` to be enabled as well. How can I do that?**

Here's what I tried:

```
[target.'cfg(feature = "rand")'.dependencies]
num-bigint = { version = "0.2", features = ["rand"] }
```

This works, but I'm receiving this warning:

```
warning: Found `feature = ...` in `target.'cfg(...)'.dependencies`. This key is not supported for selecting dependencies and will not work as expected. Use the [features] section instead: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html
```

Should I just ignore the warning, or is there a better way to do it? I checked that web page, but I cannot find anything helpful.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `"crate/feature"` in your features (as described in the [Cargo documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html)) to specify which features of dependencies that should be enabled:

```
[features]
enable-rand = ["rand", "num-bigint/rand"]
```

Note that the feature needs to have a name that does not conflict with the name of a dependency, as optional dependencies create implicit features, and you cannot set those to enable other features this way. (The implementation of this functionality is being tracked in Cargo issue [#5565](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5565), if you're interested.)

Comment: That fails with: `Features and dependencies cannot have the same name: \`rand\``

Comment: @prosc Yes, I've updated the answer with some more details around that.

Comment: Mh, so there's no way to do that without renaming the feature? That would be a big inconvenience for me

Comment: @prosc Yes, as I've mentioned in my answer it's a feature in the works, but currently it's not possible to do.