# How to include dependency based on optional dependency?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In Rust Cargo, how can I include optional features of dependencies, depending on the inclusion of another dependency?

Specifically, I would like to offer a "serde" feature, which enables serde support. What I can do is [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61090286/cargo-toml-how-do-i-select-a-dependencys-feature-based-on-my-crates-features)]

```toml
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", optional = true }
```

Rust exports this dependency as a feature automatically (as I understand it).
However, I use other dependencies, which offer a "serde" feature, too:

```toml
[dependencies]
otherpackage = { version = "1.0", features = ["serde"] }
serde = { version = "1.0", optional = true }
```

Now, the serde feature of "otherpackage" should only be included if the "serde" feature is activated for this package. But cargo does not let me do

```toml
[features]
serde = [ "serde", "otherpackage/serde" ]

[dependencies]
otherpackage = { version = "1.0" }
serde = { version = "1.0", optional = true }
```

I understand this is due to a name clash between the "serde" feature and the "serde" dependency, which I think is also exported as a feature. So, in essence there are now two "serde" features, which obviously does not work.

How can I solve this with still offering a "serde" feature and without renaming the "serde" package? Ideally, I would just like to disable the automatic exporting of the serde dependency as a feature or be able to specify a feature dependency of the "serde" package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I solve this with still offering a "serde" feature and without renaming the "serde" package?

Since Rust 1.60, [“namespaced features”](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5565) allow this, as documented in [the Cargo documentation on optional dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#optional-dependencies). When referring to a crate from within your `[features]` table, prefix it with `dep:`, like this:

```ini
[features]
serde = [ "dep:serde", "otherpackage/serde" ]

[dependencies]
otherpackage = { version = "1.0" }
serde = { version = "1.0", optional = true }
```

As soon as you use `dep:` for an optional dependency, it is no longer treated as implicitly creating a feature, so this also allows giving an entirely different name to the feature than to any dependencies it enables.

---

**The following solution is obsolete and included for historical reference.**

Prior to namespaced features, this had to be done by renaming the “serde” dependency. However, this doesn't need to disrupt anything else; as described in [“Advanced Cargo [features] Usage”](https://blog.turbo.fish/cargo-features/), you can rename it and rename it *back.* Set up your Cargo.toml like this:

```toml
[features]
serde = [ "serde_cr", "otherpackage/serde" ]

[dependencies]
otherpackage = { version = "1.0" }
serde_cr = { package = "serde", version = "1.0", optional = true }
```

This will make the crate name `serde_cr` visible to your code. Then rename it back using an explicit `extern crate` in your `lib.rs`:

```rust
extern crate serde_cr as serde;
```

However, this has the disadvantage of causing your package to have a feature named `serde_cr`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know it is possible to rename a crate back in lib.rs. However, it seems that this solution requires an ugly hack when using `derive(Deserialize)`, because rustc complains that it `can't find crate for "serde"`. Using `#[serde(crate = "serde")]` below each `derive(Deserialize)` solves the issue: [how to reexport Serialize, Deserialize?](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1465#issuecomment-800686252)

Comment: Namespaced features has been merged and stabilized if I'm reading correctly. Should this answer be updated?

Comment: @kmdreko Done. I kept the old version since it explains what one might see in old libraries.

Comment: @KevinReid wow! quick work!