# Cargo.toml: how to conditionally enable a dependency feature?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

In my project, I have 2 features: `myfeatureA` and `myfeatureB`.

I want one of them to depend on `tokio` with features `rt` and `sync`, and the other to depend on `tokio` with only the feature `sync`.

I tried this configuration in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.32", features = ["rt", "sync"], optional = true }

[features]
myfeatureA = ["dep:tokio"]
myfeatureB = ["dep:tokio/sync"]
```

```
$ cargo build --features=myfeatureB
error: failed to parse manifest at `[...]/myproject/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  feature `myfeatureB` includes `dep:tokio/sync` with both `dep:` and `/`
  To fix this, remove the `dep:` prefix.
```

So, I removed the `dep:` prefix (this is the solution provided by this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61090286/cargo-toml-how-do-i-select-a-dependencys-feature-based-on-my-crates-features), but it does not work):

```ini
[features]
myfeatureA = ["dep:tokio"]
myfeatureB = ["tokio/sync"]
```

```
$ cargo build --features=myfeatureB
error: Package `myproject v0.1.0 ([...]/myproject)` does not have feature `tokio`. It has an optional dependency with that name, but that dependency uses the "dep:" syntax in the features table, so it does not have an implicit feature with that name.
```

How can I make `myfeatureB` depend on `tokio` with only the `sync` feature?

Comment: The second approach (`tokio/sync`) works for me, though it didn't always worked. Verify you have the latest Rust version installed.

Comment: Not if you use `"dep:tokio"` for another feature.

Comment: Even if you use `dep:tokio` for another feature. Again, make sure you have the latest Rust version installed.

Comment: Oh that's true, I was using Rust 1.70, I just upgraded to 1.72 and now I can use `"dep:tokio"` for the other feature. However, `"dep:tokio/sync"` still does not work (so it's inconsistent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was reported in [issue #10788](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10788), which was fixed for Rust 1.72.0. Now you can use the second approach (no `dep:`).

For previous versions, don't use `dep:` at all, even for other features. This creates a feature named `tokio`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not using `dep:` at all (contrary to what the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#optional-dependencies) suggests) works:

```ini
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.32", features = ["rt", "sync"], optional = true }

[features]
myfeatureA = ["tokio"]
myfeatureB = ["tokio/sync"]
```

I guess the `dep:` mechanism is not fully implemented yet.

EDIT: with Rust 1.72, the second example from the original post works ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77057406/cargo-toml-how-to-conditionally-enable-a-dependency-feature#comment135844090_77057406)):

```ini
[features]
myfeatureA = ["dep:tokio"]
myfeatureB = ["tokio/sync"]
```